# Serializing/Deserializing large object single time Vs Serializing/Deserializing small objects multiple times?

Tags: c#, serialization

I need to deserialize my object from database on every page load and serialize again in database on hit of next button. I want to know which will be fastest way to load/save page.
Should I split my big object in 3-4 small objects and serialize/deserialize 3-4 times. In this way I will talk to database 3-4 time and initialize XMLSerializer 3-4 time.
Other way is to serialize/deserialize complete object, which will have single database hit and  single initialization of XMLSerializer. But XML stream (serialized data) will be large.
Which option will be fastest?

Comment: Why don't you write a test program to time each method?

Comment: What is this data? is it some form of application state?

Comment: Frankly, your biggest problem here is going to be bandwidth; so a: I wouldn't be using XmlSerializer (something more terse like protobuf-net seems appropriate), and b: I wouldn't be storing *this particular* data in a SQL database - I'd be storing it in some kind of key/value store, such as redis

Answer (score 0):

Serializing/De serializing a complete object with asynchronous model may be helpful.

Async model : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164128.aspx#S4

Answer (score 0):

In most cases calling the database will be your biggest performance bottleneck. So without knowing more detail than what you posted, I would lean toward using a single large object. You might do better if you can parallelize 3-4 smaller requests, but that's likely more complex and more likely to cause scaling issues sooner.

Follow-up questions that might point you at better answers:

- How big is each object?
- How many users will make concurrent requests to this code?
- Are there an limitations on memory, database connections, or other capacity?